# Possible to access controls on parent page from SharePoint popup?

Tags: web-part, popup

I have a web part from which I am popping up a aspx page that is used to upload a file.  Code:

```
<a href="javascript:SP.UI.ModalDialog.OpenPopUpPage('/_layouts/MyProject/UploadFile.aspx');">
```

When I am done with my popup aspx page I would like to refresh a control on the original page (or the entire page) because there have been changes made that should be reflected.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use the .parent property on your current object. Eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/183702/access-parents-parent-from-javascript-object

Another way is by using jQuery as seen here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726816/how-to-write-this-in-jquery-window-parent-document-getelementbyidparentprice

Comment: Ended up using `window.parent.location.reload(true);` in case anyone needs this.

Answer (score 3):

In your code behind, render this to close the popup

```
            Context.Response.Write("<script type='text/javascript'>window.frameElement.commitPopup();</script>");
            Context.Response.Flush();
            Context.Response.End();
```

And change your javascript link to refresh the page when the popup closes:

```
javascript:SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog({url:"{SiteUrl}/_layouts/",dialogReturnValueCallback: function(dialogResult, returnValue) { SP.UI.ModalDialog.RefreshPage(SP.UI.DialogResult.OK) }})
```

Comment: btw this is for modal popup, not a popup page, but you may be able to adapt it for your scenario

Comment: Can't seem to get it to work with a popup instead of a modal dialog